# PASAR UN INPUT FILE A OTRO INPUT Y MOSTRAR DOCUMENTO

Tags: javascript, input

quisiera saber como podria enviar un input file a una tabla html para que se listen y asi poder enviar en lote mis documentos.

Como muestra la imagen solo sale la ruta... por lo que necesito que que se almacene en la tabla para luego enviarlo

Gracias.

[image: Imagen de mi tabla para poder subir]

Comment: Se recomienda no almacenar archivos como imágenes, documentos, audios, etcétera en bases de datos, lo que se almacena en tablas son las rutas donde se aloja el recurso, ¿estas usando un MVC?, comenta en tu post que hay en el backend.

Comment: No almacenaré los archivos en la base de datos solo la ruta como backend... lo que ahora quiero es listar en la tabla html los campos de arriba para asi enviarlos

Comment: Pero en tu imagen se ve que ya agregaste el archivo....la verdad no entiendo lo que quieres.

Comment: Creo que no me deje entender... lo que quiero hacer es que cuando agregue el documento saber la forma que cuando le de clic me habra el documento como vista previa.